# How can I display a view controller on top of another view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, overlay

In iOS 9, how can I display a view controller as an overlay on top of another view controller. I have a map view with pins the have buttons on them. I would like it so when you tap the button on the annotation it will present a view controller on top of the map (not full screen, but some padding around) showing more detail. This VC will have buttons and a small collection view on it. The background will be blurred, probably with a `FXBlurView` and it will be tap outside to dismiss. Is there any way to achieve this with an iPhone? Also, the view must be done through interface builder as there are a lot of elements to go through. How exactly should I go about this? (Sorry if it looks a bit like do it for me, I just want to give as much info about my needs as possible).

Comment: hmm.... would I have to add the not full screen and tap outside to dismiss myself or just done in storyboard?

Comment: user KGModel Controller for same.